# Why are my LaTeX block-quotes not being formatted by Pandoc?

Tags: latex, docx, pandoc, quote

I am trying to format my thesis which I have written in LaTeX, but I cannot get Pandoc to pass my block-quotes through correctly.

Here is my minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\addbibresource{/home/dan/Documents/Academic-Writing/bibliography/general.bib}
\addbibresource{./dissertation.bib}
\begin{document}


Beginning this dissertation by defining covenant is necessary for two
reasons.  First, covenant is foundational to this dissertation.  I
cannot argue for anything based off of covenant until it is well
understood.  Second, and perhaps more importantly, covenant is clearly
a central theme of Scripture.  As Williamson puts it:
\begin{quote}
Covenant is without doubt one of the most important motifs in Biblical
theology, attested to not only by the traditional labels applied to
the respective parts of the Christian Bible, but also by the fact that
the concept looms large at important junctures throughout the Bible.
It underpins God’s relationship with Noah, Abraham, Israel, the
Levitical priesthood and the Davidic dynasty.  It is also used with
respect to God’s relationship with the reconstituted `Israel' of the
future.  Therefore, while `Biblical' and `covenant theology' must
certainly not be confused as synonymous, covenant is indisputably one
of the Bible’s core theological themes.\footcites[][
  29.]{williamson07:-seale-with-oath}
\end{quote}

\section{Biblical Accounts of Covenant}
\label{sec:org4027f61}
The number of covenants between God and his people explicitly attested
to in Scripture is debated.  Some covenants are explicitly called
`covenant' in Scripture.  Others are not thus called in but yet retain
all the forms.  Of the covenants explicitly labeled \emph{berith}
there are at least five, but there may be as many as ten.  At a
minimum God has made covenants with Noah, Abraham and the patriarchs,
Israel through Moses, David, and the people in the New covenant.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I use the following command to create my Word file with pandoc

```sh
pandoc -s Compile-This2.tex --reference-doc=/home/dan/Documents/Academic-Writing/dissertation/submissions/reference.docx --citeproc --bibliography=/home/dan/Documents/Academic-Writing/bibliography/general.bib --csl=/home/dan/Documents/Academic-Writing/dissertation/turabian-fullnote-bibliography-8th-edition.csl -o minimal.docx --verbose
```

The reference document has both a Block Quote and Quote environment built in with the proper formatting.  However the output file which should make the second paragraph a block-quote does not.  The output looks like:
[image: This word Document]

I have also tried multiple different LaTeX setups, but none seem to pass through to the word document.  For example using `\begin{blockquote}` just outputs a skip in Pandoc.

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/697008/36296